# Java folder missing from openCV installation with homebrew

Tags: macos, java, homebrew, opencv

On my old MacBook Pro mid 2012 I was able to easily install openCV 4.5.2 with homebrew. After installation I had a java folder with a dylib file and a jar.
Now I bought a MacBook Pro M2 2022, installed homebrew and then openCV 4.7.0 but I don't see the java folder. Why is that?

Since with `brew edit opencv` I was getting

> Error: Invalid usage: opencv doesn't exist on disk.

I have tried to first execute  `brew install --build-from-source opencv`, then I used the vim editor with: `brew edit opencv` and changed the build for java from OFF to ON. And then after that I tried: `brew reinstall --build-from-source opencv` but I still don't see the java folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the same issue as the link below?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76097556/homebrew-on-mac-not-using-the-edited-opencv-rb-file-via-brew-edit-opencv-during

Comment: @miniminime yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this using maven and add the following dependency. this hsould help

```
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
<artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
<version>4.7.0-0</version>
 </dependency>
```